# WCF client throws SocketException if I'm also running a Fiddler

Tags: wcf, fiddler

I'm trying to use Fiddler2 to inspect SOAP messages exchanged between WCF client and WCF service ( both client and service are running on  same machine). But problem is, whenever I use Fiddler2, WCF client reports

*"EndpointnotFoundException:There was no endpoint listening at http://a-PC:8100 that could accept the message à System.Net.WebException: Unable   to connect to the remote server - à System.Net.Sockets-SocketException:An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:8888"*

Thank you

Comment: This should work just fine in Fiddler. You haven't explained what your exact steps are?

Comment: It turns out it’s not working because when using fiddler, client tried each time to access the internet and zone alarm automatically denied it an access. Once I reconfigured zone alarm to allow client to access the internet, it started working, though it’s a bit slower now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can't say for sure that fiddler was the issue here I would recommend using an soap/endpoint testing tool like [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) will probably do a better job of letting you inspect your messages than fiddler will anyway.

Comment: ok, I've installed soapUI, and created a new project, launched HTtp Monitor (first as Http Proxy and then as Http Tunnel), but nothing is happening. Meaning no trafic is captured by soapUI even thought WCF client and service are exchanging messages. Any ideas how to set soapUI to intercept SOAP messages?

Comment: @user437291 The idea with soapUI isn't to intercept the messages, it is to create and send messages as the client and inspect the responses.

Comment: I hope this will make some sense: I added WSDL ( created by WCF service ) to soapUI's project. But when soapUI generates request to a particular operation, it only supplies a template, while values for operation's parameters need to be inserted into this request manually. But I don't know how to specify these values within SOAP message. Is there a way I could simply instruct soapUI what values to place inside a request?

Comment: @user437291 Well in the free version you just need to input the values into the xml manually, it should have the full message defined by the WSDL of the service for you with question marks where values should go. In the pro version it has a gui message editor and a few nice features to help you generate requests with vs direct xml editing. Also you can setup soapUI as mock service and send the request from your wcf client app to the mock service endpoint to get a properly filled message, then use that message as a base for your test messages.

Comment: uhm, when trying to run mock service I get  "MultiException[java.io.IOException:Unable to establish loopback connection]"